# Android: Get pixel from camera displaying on imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, drawable, android-imageview

I have displaying camera preview on imageview. I want to know the value of a pixel at a position  imageview but my Aplication can't be installed and has been stopped on android phone. my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private CameraPreview camPreview;
private ImageView MyCameraPreview = null;
private FrameLayout mainLayout;
private TextView colorRGB;
private static int PreviewSizeWidth = 640;
private int PreviewSizeHeight = 480;
//private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyCameraPreview = new ImageView(this);

    SurfaceView camView = new SurfaceView(this);
    SurfaceHolder camHolder = camView.getHolder();
    camPreview = new CameraPreview(PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, MyCameraPreview);

    camHolder.addCallback(camPreview);

    mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout1);

    mainLayout.addView(camView, new LayoutParams(PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight));
    mainLayout.addView(MyCameraPreview,new LayoutParams(PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight));

    colorRGB=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    float Ex=48;
    float Ey=28;
    float[] eventXY = new float[]{Ex,Ey};

    Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
    MyCameraPreview.getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

    invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
    int x=Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]);
    int y=Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);

    Drawable imgDrawable = MyCameraPreview.getDrawable();

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();
    int getRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
    colorRGB.setText(Integer.toHexString(getRGB));

   }
```

Error Log Reports:

> 06-05 19:07:59.610: E/AndroidRuntime(6665): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-05 19:07:59.610: E/AndroidRuntime(6665): at com.proyek.androsign2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
>   06-05 19:07:59.610: E/AndroidRuntime(6665):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>   06-05 19:07:59.610: E/AndroidRuntime(6665):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   06-05 19:07:59.610: E/AndroidRuntime(6665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in your logcat: NullPointerException

If I were you, go through line by line and check which method is returning null. It's most likely getDrawable() or getBitmap()

Comment: the main problem is in getBitmap().

Comment: this is because you haven't set any image on the ImageView MyCameraPreview. Are you trying to retrieve the bitmap from the camera preview or from resources/assets? If you need the camera preview as a bitmap then you need to look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html and then convert the byte[] data into bitmap format.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the bitmap from camera preview. I've declared public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) in CameraPreview class. Should I declare onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) again in MainActivity class?

Answer (score -1):

you should do it in a seperate thread as your bitmap or drawable NOT yet created.